# How to display only some requests in Apache Log Wiewer?

Tags: regex, apache, logging

I would like to display only those requests that has nothing to do with image files (e.g. `.png` and `.jpg` files). I tried using regex in custom log field:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\/^((?!png).)*$/s" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
```

However it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with the `LogFormat` directive, instead use [`CustomLog`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_log_config#customlog):

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
SetEnvIf Request_URI \.(gif|png)$ is-image
CustomLog "/path/to/logs/requests.log" combined env=!is-image
```

Comment: Is there any way how to make it within the Apache Logs Wiewer interface?

Comment: @SerialyCz I haven't used Apache Logs Viewer. The above code will work if you put this directly onto your web server's config.